# Operation on multiple mapped currency columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes namely df1 and df2. I want to perform operation on column "Amount_Dollar" from df2. Basically in df1 I have historical currency data and I want to perform datewise operation given Currency and Amount_Dollar from df2 to calculate the values for New_Amount_Dollar column in df2.

For 'Currency' == [AUD, BWP] We need to multiply the Amount_Dollar by respective currency value for respective date.

If any currency is not available in df1 then don't perform any operation on "Amount_Dollar" (means take the same value)

For other available currencies we need to divide the Amount_Dollar by respective currency value for respective date.

e.g In df2 I have first currency as AUD for Date = '01-01-2019', so I want to calculate New_Amount_Dollar value such that

New_Amount_Dollar = Amount_Dollar*AUD value from df1 i.e New_Amount_Dollar = 19298*98 = 1891204

another example where in df2 I have third currency as COP for Date = '03-01-2019, so I want to calculate New_Amount_Dollar value such that

New_Amount_Dollar = Amount_Dollar/COP value from df1 i.e New_Amount_Dollar = 5000/0.043 = 116279.06

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Date':['01-01-2019', '02-01-2019', '03-01-2019', 
                 '04-01-2019','05-01-2019'],
        'AUD':[98, 98.5, 99, 99.5, 97],
        'BWP':[30, 31, 33, 32, 31],
        'CAD':[0.02, 0.0192, 0.0196, 0.0196, 0.0192],
        'BND':[0.99, 0.952, 0.970, 0.980, 0.970],
        'COP':[0.05, 0.047, 0.043, 0.047, 0.045]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'Date':['01-01-2019', '02-01-2019', '03-01-2019', '04-01-2019','05-01-2019'],
        'Currency':['AUD','AUD','COP','NZD','BND'],
        'Amount_Dollar':[19298, 19210, 5000, 200, 2300],
        'New_Amount_Dollar':[0,0,0,0,0]
        }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

df1

```
         Date    AUD  BWP     CAD    BND    COP
0  01-01-2019   98.0   30  0.0200  0.990  0.050
1  03-01-2019   98.5   31  0.0192  0.952  0.047
2  04-01-2019   99.0   33  0.0196  0.970  0.043
3  05-01-2019   99.5   32  0.0196  0.980  0.047
4  06-01-2019   97.0   31  0.0192  0.970  0.045
5  09-01-2019  100.0   20  0.2000  0.230  0.023
```

df2

```
         Date Currency  Amount_Dollar  New_Amount_Dollar
0  01-01-2019      AUD          19298                  0
1  02-01-2019      AUD          19210                  0
2  03-01-2019      COP           5000                  0
3  04-01-2019      NZD            200                  0
4  07-01-2019      BND           2300                  0
```

Expected result

```
         Date Currency  Amount_Dollar  New_Amount_Dollar
0  01-01-2019      AUD          19298         1891204.00
1  02-01-2019      AUD          19210         1892185.00
2  03-01-2019      COP           5000          116279.06
3  04-01-2019      NZD            200             200.00
4  05-01-2019      BND           2300            2371.13
```

Comment: Why was `CAD` still `200`, there is a currency available. I would expect `200 / 0.0196`

Comment: Sorry Its my bad. Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

First, unstack df1 to get a column of all FX, later will be used for join:

```
df1.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1.unstack(), columns = ['FX'])
```

Then join with df2. Add a mask to  CAD and BWP, take inverse of CAD/BWP. Then do column wise operation to get the new amount.

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1, left_on = ['Currency', 'Date'], right_index = True, how = 'left').fillna(1)
df2['mask'] = df2['Currency'].isin(['AUD', 'BWP'])
df2.loc[df2['mask'], 'FX'] = 1/df2.loc[df2['mask'], 'FX']
df2['New_Amount_Dollar'] = df2['Amount_Dollar'] / df2['FX']
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how `CAD` is the only currency that doesn't change its value, I am guessing that you are trying to convert the currency to `CAD`. However, the CAD rates in `df1` seem a little wacky.

Anyhow, here's the code:

```
# Format the data in `df1` to have the same general shape as `df2`
fx = pd.melt(df1, id_vars='Date', var_name='Currency', value_name='Rate')

# Exclude certain currencies from the conversion
exclude = ['CAD']
fx = fx[~fx.isin(exclude)]

# Some rates we multiply, some rates we divide
# Here, we convert the rate so the next step only involves multiplication
divide = ['COP']
fx['Rate'] = np.where(fx['Currency'].isin(divide), 1 / fx['Rate'], fx['Rate'])

# Perform the actual conversion
df2.merge(fx, how='left', on=['Date', 'Currency']) \
    .assign(New_Amount_Dollar=lambda df: df['Amount_Dollar'] * df['Rate'].fillna(1)) \
    .drop(columns='Rate')
```

Comment: it should not be hardcoded as i don't know which currency is absent unless i check it. It should check dynamically.